# Unable to Send Spark Data Frame to Kafka (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka.)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am facing issue while pushing data to Kafka with Spark data frame.

Let me explain my scenario in detail with sample example. I want to load the data to spark and send the spark output to kafka. I am using Gradle 3.5 and Spark 2.3.1 & Kafka 1.0.1

Here is build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
 }

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.sample'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.1')
compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.1')
compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')
compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

And here is my code:

```
package com.sample
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object SparkConnection {

case class emp(empid:Integer, empname:String, empsal:Float)

def main(args:Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark 
    Connection").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val dataRdd = sc.textFile("/home/sample/data/sample.txt")
    val mapRdd = dataRdd.map(row => row.split(","))
    val empRdd = mapRdd.map( row => emp(row(0).toInt, row(1), row(2).toFloat))

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val empDF = empRdd.toDF() 

    empDF.
    select(to_json(struct(empDF.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value"))
    .write.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("topic", "my-kafka-topic").save()

    }

  }
```

Please ignore spring boot framework API in build.gradle.

After build my package using Gradle, I can able to see all dependent classes mentioned in .gradle file.

But when I run the code with spark-submit like

```
spark-submit --class com.sample.SparkConnection spark_kafka_integration.jar
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:241)
    at com.iniste.SparkConnection$.main(SparkConnection.scala:29)
    at com.iniste.SparkConnection.main(SparkConnection.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
    ... 13 more
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@51684e4a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bd4cb4ef-3883-4c26-a93f-f355b13ef306
2018-09-05 17:41:17 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-156dfdbd-cff4-4c70-943f-35ef403a01ed
```

Please help me to get out of this error. And some of the blogs they suggested me to use --packages option with spark-submit. But there is some proxy limitation with me which is required to download the mentioned packages. But I am unable to understand that why spark-submit is unable to fetch the jars which are already  available. Please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need Gradle to create a shadow Jar for you, but if there is a a proxy, then Gradle also should not be able to download those packages

Comment: But my local desktop where I am running my Gradle tool doesn't have any proxy issue. My Spark node has proxy issue.

Comment: Try to see if you can get this to work https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow Also, Spark Core, Spark SQL, and Streaming should be excluded from the end jar because those packages are already part of the Spark distribution. Note: You need to add Streaming to your Gradle still `org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.3.1`

Comment: I solved the issue by adding depending jars with --jars option while running the spark-submit. But still I have a doubt that why spark-submit is not able to pick the jars even though  my project contains all dependent jars.

And for your comment, I will exclude those packages. But I am not using spark_streaming for my requirement. So for me that jar is not required

Comment: If you didn't shade/shadow the project, it will not include the dependent libraries. Kafka isn't included in the Spark package, so it'll be needed to be downloaded separately, which is what you've done. Plus, the Kafka package requires the streaming package itself, so you actually are using it

Answer (score 0):

As with any Spark applications, spark-submit is used to launch your application. spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 and its dependencies can be directly added to spark-submit using --packages, such as below in your case

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1 com.sample.SparkConnection spark_kafka_integration.jar
```

This can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying)

However, as per cricket_007 suggestions i have added the shadowjar to your build.gradle 
So the new one may look similar to this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.4"
}
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"

group = 'com.sample'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.1')
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.1')
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')
    compile ('org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1')
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
    //compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.10', version: '0.8.0'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
shadowJar{
    baseName = "spark_kafka_integration"
    zip64 true
    classifier = null
    version = null
}
```

So to create your jar the command would be just :shadowJar from your gradle.

Comment: I can't use external plugins like com.github.johnrengelman.shadow